# Python Web Scraping: Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with the scraping of a web page. I'm trying to get the difference of points (Ex: +2,+1,...) between two teams but when I apply the find_all method it returns an empty list...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
url='https://www.mismarcadores.com/partido/Q942gje8/#punto-a-punto;1'
response=get(url)
html_soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')


html_soup.find_all('span',class_='match-history-diff-score-inc')
```

Comment: Looks like the content you're looking for is not loaded on when beautifulsoup scrapes the page. It looks like it may be dynamically loaded onto the page and beautifulsoup isn't able to pick it up. I would recommend looking at [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) for problems like this

Comment: Selenium would make it slow, track down the network from the browser,find that particular request then you can use requests + bs4 to solve your problem. Trust me your code will be 5 times faster.

Answer (score 8):

The problem you have is the web content is being generated dynamically through JavaScript. As such, requests is unable to handle it, and so you'd be better off using something like [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html).

**EDIT:** Per @λuser's suggestion, I've modified my answer to only use Selenium by searching for the elements you're looking for by XPath. **Note** that I used the XPath function `starts-with()` to get both `match-history-diff-score-dec` and `match-history-diff-score-inc`. Selecting only one of them was making you miss out on almost half of the relative score updates. This is why the output yields 103 results instead of 56.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.mismarcadores.com/partido/Q942gje8/#punto-a-punto;1")

table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td//span[starts-with(@class, "match-history-diff-score-")]')

results = []
for tag in table:
    print(tag.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
print(results)
```

This outputs:

```
['+2', '+1', '+2', '+2', '+1', '+2', '+4', '+2', '+2', '+4', '+7', '+5', '+8', '+5', '+7', '+5', '+3', '+2', '+5', '+3', '+5', '+3', '+5', '+6', '+4', '+6', '+7', '+6', '+5', '+2', '+4', '+2', '+5', '+7', '+6', '+8', '+5', '+3', '+1', '+2', '+1', '+4', '+7', '+5', '+8', '+6', '+9', '+11', '+10', '+9', '+11', '+9', '+10', '+11', '+9', '+7', '+5', '+3', '+2', '+1', '+3', '+1', '+3', '+2', '+1', '+3', '+2', '+4', '+1', '+2', '+3', '+6', '+3', '+5', '+2', '+1', '+1', '+2', '+4', '+3', '+2', '+4', '+1', '+3', '+5', '+7', '+5', '+8', '+7', '+6', '+5', '+4', '+1', '+4', '+6', '+9', '+7', '+9', '+7', '+10', '+11', '+12', '+10']
```

Comment: If you're using selenium, why parsing the source a second time with Beautifulsoup? Selenium can already do XPath querying and extract text for you.

Comment: Yes you are correct. It's kind of superfluous. Maybe I will edit my answer to a solution using only Selenium.

Answer (score 7):

`Selenium` might solve your problem but I suggest you track down the network from your browser and find the request that is generating the data you need. In your case it was `d_mh_Q942gje8_es_1`.

I don't prefer `Selenium` because it is too heavy and makes your script slow. It was built for automated testing, not web scraping.

Here is my script using `requests` which undoubtedly runs faster than Selenium.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://d.mismarcadores.com/x/feed/d_mh_Q942gje8_es_1'

r = requests.get(url, headers={'x-fsign':'SW9D1eZo'}) # Got this from browser
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
diff_list = [diff.text for diff in soup.find_all('span',{'class' : 'match-history-diff-score-inc'})]
print(diff_list)
```

Output:

```
['+2', '+1', '+2', '+2', '+2', '+4', '+2', '+4', '+7', '+8', '+7', '+5', '+5', '+5', '+6', '+6', '+7', '+4', '+5', '+7', '+8', '+1', '+2', '+4', '+7', '+8', '+9', '+11', '+11', '+10', '+11', '+1', '+3', '+3', '+3', '+4', '+2', '+3', '+6', '+5', '+1', '+1', '+2', '+4', '+4', '+3', '+5', '+7', '+8', '+4', '+6', '+9', '+9', '+10', '+11', '+12']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check the page source (for example via view-source: in Chrome or Firefox, or by writing your html string to a file) you'll see that the element you are looking for (search `match-history-diff-score-inc`) is not there. In fact, the rates are loaded dynamically using JS.